# WPF BasedOn Styling

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, styles

Hey I'm trying to style buttons in WPF. I have a base style:

```
    <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate x:Name="ButtonBaseControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="#9BC4E2" BorderBrush="Black"
                            BorderThickness="3,3,3,3" CornerRadius="7,7,7,7" Padding="5,5,5,5">
                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" x:Name="Content"
                                      ContentSource="Content"
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
             <-- Removed triggers here -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But I need to use this for toggle buttons too, just to change the IsChecked background colour. But I can't access the border to set the background when I try like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"  Value="White"/> <-- Need to specify target name of the border here somehow -->
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Any suggestions? ta

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is pretty much what TemplateBinding is designed for

http://devlicio.us/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2008/07/04/templatebinding-a-bridge-between-styles-and-templates.aspx

Change the `Border.Background` property to be

```
Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
```

and add this Setter to your buttonStyle Style

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#9BC4E2" />
```

Then you can declare your `ToggleButton`s like this

```
<ToggleButton Content="ToggleButton" Background="Green" />
```

Comment: That works well thanks, we have a working solution from this!